# Native v8::Promise Result

Tags: c++, node.js, promise, v8

I'm trying to call a JS-function from C++ using v8/[Nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/) which in turn returns a Promise.

Assuming I have a generic Nan Callback

```
Nan::Callback fn
```

I then call this function using the following code

```
Nan::AsyncResource resource(Nan::New<v8::String>("myresource").ToLocalChecked());
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> value = resource.runInAsyncScope(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), fn, 0, 0);
```

The function is being called correctly, and I receive the promise on the C++ side

```
v8::Handle<v8::Promise> promiseReturnObject = 
v8::Handle<v8::Promise>::Cast ( value.ToLocalChecked() );
```

I can then check the state of the promise using

```
v8::Promise::PromiseState promiseState = promiseReturnObject->State();
```

Of course at the time the promise is still pending, and I can't access it's result. The only way I've found so far to receive the result of that promise is by using the `Then` method on the `promiseReturnObject`.

```
promiseReturnObject->Then(Nan::GetCurrentContext(), callbackFn);
```

Is there any way to retreive that result **synchronously** in the scope of the function that calls `fn`? I've tried using `std::promise` and passing it to as a `data` argument to `v8::FunctionTemplate` of `callbackFn`, but calling `wait` or `get` on the respective `std::future` blocks the execution and the promise is never fulfilled. Do I need to resort to callbacks?

Any help or idea on how I could set this up would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I derived an answer from https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5691

```
  if (result->IsPromise()) {
    Local<Promise> promise = result.As<Promise>();
    if (promise->HasHandler()) {
      while (promise->State() == Promise::kPending) {
        Isolate::GetCurrent()->RunMicrotasks();
      }
      if (promise->State() == Promise::kRejected) {
        Nan::ThrowError(promise->Result());
      }
      else
      {
        // ... procses promise->Result() ...
      }
    }
  }
```