# How to synchronously resolve a promise from the c++ node.js library

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

[Native v8::Promise Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497160/native-v8promise-result) is my question but the solution is not working. It gets stuck in the while loop which makes me think that PerformMicrotaskCheckpoint is not causing the promise to resolve itself. Here is my code:

```
  v8::Locker locker(isolate);
  v8::Isolate::Scope isolateScope(isolate);
  v8::HandleScope handleScope(isolate);
  v8::Local<v8::Context> localContext = v8::Local<v8::Context>::New(isolate, context);
  v8::Context::Scope contextScope(localContext);
  escape(html);
  std::string code = "const html = '" + html + "';";
  code += "render(html);";
  v8::Local<v8::Value> returnVal = run(code, localContext);
  v8::Local<v8::Promise> promise = returnVal.As<v8::Promise>();
  while (promise->State() == v8::Promise::kPending) {
    isolate->PerformMicrotaskCheckpoint();
  }
  return promise->State() != v8::Promise::kRejected ? *v8::String::Utf8Value(isolate, promise->Result()) : "";
```

Also the node library I am using is different. I am using https://github.com/nodejs/node not Nan.

Comment: How do you know the Promise will ever resolve? And if you know that it does, are you sure it will do so when working on the next microtask queue? Also, why not just attach a callback with `->Then(…)`?

Comment: I tried to use ->Then but that didn't work either(Might have not setup the callbacks correctly) and it seems to be asynchronous so I was not sure how I could use the value of the promise when it is resolved (the program requires the result of the promise to continue). I am not very familiar with js or node, why wouldn't the promise resolve? Should I add my JS code aswell? It basically uses puppeteer to get a screenshot of a rendered html document.

Comment: cause it‘s a promise, not a guarantee. If you wait for it synchronously, it might hang forever

Comment: „ the program requires the result of the promise to continue“ - this seems to be your actual problem